# if it is correct way of doing race condition in swift?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, race-condition

Want to try to make simple race condition and use dispatch_barrier to solve it.

A have hesitations about it because the value is around 1000 usually a bit more, but I suppose that should be something bigger as I saw on youtube videos.

```
 class A {
      var someValue = 0

      func increaseValueBy1000() {
        for _ in 0..<1000 {
          let v = self.someValue + 1
          print(v)
          self.someValue = v
        }
      }
    }


    let instance1 = A()



    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)) {
      instance1.increaseValueBy1000()
    }


    instance1.increaseValueBy1000()
```

If it is correct race condition example or not?

Comment: I'd remove `print(v)` from the loop. Who knows, what if printing is synchronised?

Comment: but how do i know if I got wrong value of v or not?

Comment: @wm.p1us use NSLog instead print

Answer (score 1):

Here is a race condition demo:

```
import Foundation

var x = 0

func setX(y: Int) {
    x = y
}

let sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(1)
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)

let q = dispatch_queue_create("demo.race-condition", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT)
dispatch_suspend(q)

// Schedule a number of concurrent tasks
for i in 0 ..< 32 {
    dispatch_async(q) {
        setX(i)
    }
}

// Schedule a completion handler
dispatch_barrier_async(q) {
    print("x: \(x)")
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema)
}

// Start running all the scheduled tasks
dispatch_resume(q)
// Wait until done
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```

There is *no* right value here *if* you understand what actualy should happen.

Comment: Ok, but what actually wrong in my example if it is not showing race condition?

Comment: Maybe it shows, but don't demonstrate clearly. This example clearly demonstrates race condition by printing different `x` from run to run.

Comment: What's important, your program may terminate when the background job is _not yet_ completed.

Comment: Try to run several times, try to increase the number of concurrent tasks and you will see.